# c# Checking whether a port is actively listening?

Tags: c#, sockets

I use the following piece of code to achieve this goal:

```
    public static bool IsServerListening()
    {
        var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("201.212.1.167"), 2593);
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            socket.Connect(endpoint, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException exception)
        {
            if (exception.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.TimedOut)
            {
                Logging.Log.Warn("Timeout while connecting to UO server game port.", exception);
            }
            else
            {
                Logging.Log.Error("Exception while connecting to UO server game port.", exception);
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logging.Log.Error("Exception while connecting to UO server game port.", exception);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is my extension method to the `Socket` class:

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public const int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_ERROR = 10060;

    /// <summary>
    /// Connects the specified socket.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="socket">The socket.</param>
    /// <param name="endpoint">The IP endpoint.</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">The connection timeout interval.</param>
    public static void Connect(this Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var result = socket.BeginConnect(endpoint, null, null);

        bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true);
        if (!success)
        {
            socket.Close();
            throw new SocketException(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_ERROR); // Connection timed out.
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this piece of code works on my development environment but when I move it into production environment it always times out (regardless of whether I set the timeout interval to 5 or 20 seconds)

Is there some other way I could check if that IP is actively listening at that particular port?

What is the reason why I can't do this from my hosting environment?

Comment: A firewall that's active in the production network trivially explains this problem.  You are using an unusual port number on a public IP.

Comment: Why are you using exact IP?
In general [`System.Net.IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any) is better solution which listens on all IPs (if this is acceptable).

Comment: Because I want to check if that IP is listening on that port?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can run `netstat -na` from command line to see all (including listening) ports.

If you add `-b` you will also see linked executable to each connection/listening.

In .NET you can get all listening connections with [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcplisteners)

Comment: I've updated the answer - .NET solution to `netstat -na` is  `GetActiveTcpListeners` and `GetActiveTcpConnections` on the `IPGlobalProperties`.

Comment: But I want listeners at that particular IP, not the local IP

Comment: My answer shows how to check listening ports - you should *check this on the **server** side*, your sample code is **client** side. 
As @Hans mentioned firewalls normally blocks non-allowed connections.

Comment: That'd be pointless, I want to check if the server is online *and* listening on that port, it could be shutdown for all I know, and there is a website supposed to report the status of the server.

Comment: From connectivity perspective your client check code is ok. Can you *manually* check if server is listening, firewalls are configured correctly and that you can connect to the specified TPC port from your local console with telnet, [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or some other tool.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3328/discussion-between-matej-and-nico)

Answer (score 3):

You can check it by using this code:

```
       TcpClient tc = new TcpClient();
       try
       {

           tc.Connect(<server ipaddress>, <port number>);
           bool stat = tc.Connected;
           if (stat)
               MessageBox.Show("Connectivity to server available."); 

           tc.Close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Not able to connect : " + ex.Message);
           tc.Close();
       }
```